# How to open DBF(dBase) file faster way and update it very fast using VS C#?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, dbf, dbase

I want to build a program that can open dBase(DBF) file faster like other normal files.
My data contains more than 100,000 lines of data. I want to build a software, that can open DBF(dBase) file  faster way and modify it .Also I wan to import data from (.CSV) file .

Any suggession. really need help

Comment: Do these DBF files have index files? It may be that you are losing the performance the index files can bring by not using a dBase  connection.

http://www.dofactory.com/Connect/Connect.aspx#_self705 has connection strings for dBase listed.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into CodeBase.  It's a high performance DBF library. http://www.codebase.com/products/windows/

Answer (score 0):

There is also Topaz for dbf. I've used both Topaz and Codebase and both are fine.
http://www.softsci.com/p-topaz.htm

Answer (score 0):

Apollo (www.apollodb.com) is an xBase data engine that has read/write support for DBF files and indexes. It also supports .CSV import/export. It has an ADO.NET Data Provider for SQL (may not be what you want) and Direct Data Access objects (direct cursor) which sounds like what you want.